# infernojs pass data to parent component

Tags: typescript, infernojs

I am stuck in my simple **infernojs v1.2.2** app to pass data to parent component, this issue might be linked to the typescript because i got some error for typescript which are not (It has issuewith recognizing props from parent component).

I try to give a callback to my child component to call it later but I have a bad context. The work around I did make me not even triggering the onInput.

Here is my parent component

```
import { linkEvent } from 'inferno';
import Component from 'inferno-component';


import Weight from './weight';

export class RatioAlcohol extends Component<Props, any> {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
         this.state = { weight: 65 };
    }
    setChangeWeight(instance, event) {
        instance.setState({ weight: event.target.value });
    }
    render(props){
        return (
                <div className="ratio-alcohol">
                    <Weight valueChanged={ linkEvent(this, this.setChangeWeight) } weight={ this.state.weight } />
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and there my child component:

```
import { linkEvent } from 'inferno';
import Component from 'inferno-component';

export default class Weight extends Component<Props, any> {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = { weight: props.weight};
    }
    handleChangeWeight(instance, event) {
        instance.valueChanged.event();
    }
    render(props){
        return (
                <div className="weight">
                    <label for="WeightInput">What is your weight(Kg)?</label>
                    <input id="WeightInput" name="weight" type="number" value={ props.weight } onInput={ linkEvent(props, this.handleChangeWeight) } />
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I did not find an example of parent / child component interaction in the inferno documentation and I have no experience in React, I feel like I could get the answer from React app but did not get it for the moment.

I used the inferno-typescript-example as base for my project, I don't know if it matters with that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so the `handleChangeWeight` function signature in `Weight` has 1st params as instance, it's actually your component's  `props`. It should be something like

```js
export default class Weight extends Component<Props, any> {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = { weight: props.weight};
    }
    handleChangeWeight(props, event) {
        props.valueChanged(event);
    }
    render(props){
        return (
                <div className="weight">
                    <label for="WeightInput">What is your weight(Kg)?</label>
                    <input id="WeightInput" name="weight" type="number" value={ props.weight } onInput={ linkEvent(props, this.handleChangeWeight) } />
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and in RatioAlcohol you don't have to link event, rather if you need access to instance, you gotta bind your handler

```js
export class RatioAlcohol extends Component<Props, any> {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = { weight: 65 };
        this.setChangeWeight = this.setChangeWeight.bind(this)
    }
    setChangeWeight(event) {
        this.setState({ weight: event.target.value });
    }
    render(props){
        return (
                <div className="ratio-alcohol">
                    <Weight valueChanged={ this.setChangeWeight } weight={ this.state.weight } />
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do that i have an error in the RatioAlcohol  when the event is trigger to the parent that I do not understand : `this.setState is not a function`

Comment: I forgot to add `this.setChangeWeight = this.setChangeWeight.bind(this)` in the RatioAlcohol component